# SharePoint designer workflow compare created date between two dates that two dates in other list how I can achieve this

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, office-365

SharePoint Designer Workflow compare created date between two dates that two dates in other list how I can achieve this .

I have List1 in that i created date I want to compare list2 startdate and enddate if this created date is between these two dates I have to display some text in the list1 in some other column.

can you help me on this